# Way to transfer large amount of data between NIOS and FPGA

Tags: intel-fpga, dsp, nios-ii

I'm searching a method to transfer large amount of data (350 bytes) from NIOS processor to FPGA via Avalon Interface. The board I'm using is DE0-Nano from Altera, therefore, I'm trying to implement via the software tool Altera DSP Builder by using the Altera DSP Builder's blockset. By this time, I've figured out a way using the Avalon-MM Slave Block but each time I could only transfer 4 bytes, so I have to transfer about 88 times to get the full data package. How can I implement this in a more concise way ?

Comment: Where is the source of this data? Program memory/Data memory/others?

Comment: If you want less CPU involvement, the usual answer is DMA.

Answer (score 3):

NIOS is a 32-bit processor, and can only operate on a single 32bit data word at a time. This is why you can only transfer 4 bytes at a time.

To transfer more data, you would simply perform multiple write operations, 88 in your case. Each one would send another 4 bytes of data.

As to where you send the data, that is up to you. You could write to a meory block (e.g. M10k in the FPGA), or you could write to a FIFO and have the FPGA side stream the data out of that.

Answer (score 2):

*Finally got time to write this answer I drafted on reading the question...*

You want to perform a pretty-small bulk transfer of 350 bytes, which occupies 88 dwords.

The NIOS cannot hold 88 dwords in registers, so it does one of the following:

1. Generates each dword computationally.
2. Fetches the data from off-chip storage.
3. Reads the data from internal RAM.

(1) and (2) will have multiple instructions between each dword store. So the 88-dword bulk transfer cannot be sped up to a single bulk transfer.

(3) can be sped up. You can use a copy engine or DMA Controller (DMAC) to access the data and perform a single bulk transfer of it.

If some dual-access RAM is used then the NIOS may be able to run at full speed while the transfer happens. Dual-access RAM may use up more FPGA RAM blocks to implement.

If not, the NIOS may be held off while the transfer happens, causing a reduction in NIOS performance and in its responsiveness.